# Sum value of percentage attributes in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to sum the value of width attribute but it just concat their values

here is my code

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="//table">
    <xsl:variable name="numb" type="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:for-each select="tr/td[@width]">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(@width,'%',''))"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($numb)"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

XML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%"><p>x</p>
        </td>
        <td width="20%"><p>x</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I get the result as: `10020`

Comment: Please don't escape your XML code, it is a pain to get it into the editor that way. Instead, simply click the code-button in the editor when you post a question at S-O (or indent with four space, which is the same). It will save you the pain of tediously having to escape each `<`-character. Oh, and indent code for readability ;). Fixed it.

Comment: PS: your code is actually correct, while Martin Honnen's version is easier. The only mistake is the `type="xs:integer*`. It should be `as="xs:integer*`. Then it "just works" (considering you have not gotten an error is very, very odd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(tr/td[@width]/number(translate(@width, '%', '')))"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: IE shows the following Error: NodeTest expected here. sum(tr/td[@width]/-->number<--(translate(@width, '%', '')))

Comment: Well you tagged your question as XSLT 2.0 so please use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova to try posted code. Browsers like IE only support XSLT 1.0 where the kind of expression I posted is not supported at all.